# Image/Rich Text in Email Template

Tags: email-template, images

I want to place an image as a merge field in an email template.
The image is for a QR code which I am getting from an external system.
I prefer not to save it as a public doc so I tried putting it inside a rich text area. Problem is that gmail blocks this content.

I can also tried saving this image in its binary form and generating VF email template but this gets blocked as well.

How can I get the desired result to show in gmail

Comment: did you got a solution for this problem, I have the same requirement.